# Ruby rescue multiple specific errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date

In Rails i am trying to validate dates that are being imported through an excel document. it wont go through ActiveRecord so i cant use the [Timeliness gem](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) that i have in the system that i use to verify other dates.

So i wrote my own gem that verifies the format of a date, but there are some dates that get through that are not valid like `31/04/2013`, if the date is in an incorrect format then it will raise a `RuntimeError` which i rescue and supply a error message. but in ruby:

```
Date.new(2013,4,31)
» ArgumentError: invalid date
```

So i would like to rescue either of them. i am just afraid that some ArgumentError will appear and it wont be this exact one. so i would like it to rescue only `ArgumentError: invalid date`, is this possible?

This is the excel date checker i wrote

```
  def as_date
    return nil if self.blank?
    begin
      date = DateDojo::DateSensei.date_format_validation(self)
      if date.class == Date
        return date
      else
        return false
      end
    rescue RuntimeError
      :invalid_date_format_to_make_validations_cry_and_die_sad_face
    rescue ArgumentError
      :dates_that_wouldnt_exist_even_in_the_correct_format
    end
  end
```

Comment: Actually, your link is to the validates_timeliness gem, but the [timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/timeliness) gem is extracted from that, and does not rely upon ActiveRecord afaik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target a specific error message like so:

```
begin
  ...
rescue ArgumentError => e
  if e.message =~ /invalid date/
    # Do something
  else
    puts e.message
  end
end
```